# Changing Hexa color not changing output color in Image recoloring

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am using below code to change the color of intended object . I pass hexa code and object of image and its job is to recolor it. When i pass it in my code it always gives blue color after recoloring. I am changing hexa color but not effecting, What is issue in my code:

**Image**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Define command-line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Recolor images based on hexcode or sample image')
parser.add_argument('image_paths', metavar='path', type=str, nargs='+', help='path(s) to image(s) to recolor')
parser.add_argument('--hexcode', type=str, help='hexcode of the desired color')
parser.add_argument('--sample', type=str, help='path to a sample image to match the color')

# Parse the command-line arguments
args = parser.parse_args(['/home/hamza-developer/Pictures/1.png','--hexcode', '#0000FF'])
image_paths = args.image_paths
hexcode = args.hexcode
sample_path = args.sample

# Define color adjustments based on hexcode
def hex_to_rgb(hexcode):
    r = int(hexcode[1:3], 16)
    g = int(hexcode[3:5], 16)
    b = int(hexcode[5:7], 16)
    return (b, g, r) # OpenCV uses BGR format

# Define color adjustments based on sample image
def get_color_adjustments(sample_img):
    # Convert sample image to HSV color space for color thresholding
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(sample_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # Define color range based on hue, saturation, and value channels
    lower = np.array([hsv[:,:,0].min(), hsv[:,:,1].min(), hsv[:,:,2].min()])
    upper = np.array([hsv[:,:,0].max(), hsv[:,:,1].max(), hsv[:,:,2].max()])
    # Define color adjustments based on the color range
    color = np.array([np.mean(lower[:2]), np.mean(lower[1:]), np.mean(upper[1:])])
    diff = np.array([50, 50, 50]) # acceptable color range
    return (color, diff)

# Recolor an image based on a color adjustment
def recolor_image(img, color, diff):
    # Create a mask of pixels within the acceptable color range
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, color - diff, color + diff)
    # Replace pixels within the mask with the desired color
    img[mask > 0] = color
    return img

# Load and recolor each image
for path in image_paths:
    # Load the image
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    # Get the color adjustment
    if hexcode:
        color = hex_to_rgb(hexcode)
        diff = np.array([50, 50, 50]) # acceptable color range
    elif sample_path:
        sample_img = cv2.imread(sample_path)
        color, diff = get_color_adjustments(sample_img)
    else:
        print('Error: No color specified')
        break
    # Recolor the image
    recolored_img = recolor_image(img, color, diff)
    recolored_path = path.replace('.jpg', '_recolored.jpg')
    plt.imshow(recolored_img)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Since OpenCV uses BGR ordering (not RGB), you have to implement `hex_to_bgr()`. Also: `color - diff` and `color + diff` may exceed the range [0, 255]. For testing, I suggest you to save `mask` and make sure it's not all zeros.

Comment: @Rotem, If i use Opencv Then its color becomes its original one. Problem I think is in the recoloring. Can you tell me your solution or might upload the code of what u r thinking

Comment: I am not going to post an answer. Try debugging your code... I suggest you to save `mask` to image file, and see if the white part of the mask is what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your output is blue is that you're using BGR for OpenCV, but matplotlib expects RGB.  Replace your last couple lines with the following and the result will no longer be blue:

```
# convert the recolored image from BGR to RGB for plt 
recolored_img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(recolored_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(recolored_img_rgb)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Then its color becomes its original one. Problem I think is in the recoloring. Can you tell me your solution please !